# Import code suggestions missing after upgrading to typescript 3.0.1

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code's code actions to save time writing import statements.

For example, using `typescript@2.8.4` I could just write the name of something I want to import and there would usually be a code action available:

[image: Working example]

However if I change the typescript version used for language features in Visual Studio Code to `typescript@3.0.1` (VS Code's current version) these code actions aren't available:

[image: Not working example]

My folder structure is a pretty typical setup where `tsconfig.json` is in the root directory with `package.json` and `node_modules/` and my typescript files are in `src/`.

```
/src/MyScript.ts
/node_modules/...
/package.json
/tsconfig.json
```

The tsconfig.json file is the default generated by `react-scripts-ts`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

Why is this happening/how can I fix it? I searched github issues for typescript, and VS Code, and googled to see if anyone else is experiencing similar issues but didn't find anything for this particular problem.
I'm using the latest version of VS Code (1.26.0) on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Possibly https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26333 ?  Try installing `typescript@next` into your project and switching VS Code to use it and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Thanks, that's fixed it! Feel free to post as answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26333 ? Try installing `typescript@next` into your project and switching VS Code to use it and see if the problem goes away.